# Prefered form for returning an object/rvalue ref, from a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, rvalue

If I have a class implementing move semantics:

```
class BigObject
{
public:
    BigObject(something x = something()) { ... }
    BigObject(const BigObject& other) { ... }
    BigObject(BigObject&& other) { ... }
    BigObject& operator=(BigObject other) { ... }
    void swap(BigObject& other) { ... }
    // [...]
};


auto begin = std::begin(somethingSequence); // collection doesn't matter here
auto end = std::end(somethingSequence); // collection doesn't matter here

BigObjectOutputIterator dest; // collection doesn't matter here
```

What is the correct way to do return a BigObject in a lambda?

```
std::transform(begin, end, dest, 
    [](something x) -> BigObject {return BigObject(x); });
```

or

```
std::transform(begin, end, dest, 
    [](something x) -> BigObject&& {return std::move(BigObject(x)); });
```

or

```
std::transform(begin, end, dest, 
    [](something x) -> BigObject {return std::move(BigObject(x)); });
```

or some other form?

Thanks.

Comment: read [your next assignment](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/09/your-next-assignment/) on CppNext

Comment: Note that your question doesn't apply only to lambdas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first and third form are basically the same, since `return BigObject(x);` is an rvalue and as such the move constructor is called already.

The second form however invokes undefined behaviour, as an rvalue reference is *still just a reference*, and a reference to something that goes out of scope is still as bad as it was before.

Answer (score 3):

The first form is just fine. As a general rule, never, *ever*, return rvalue references. The third form doesn't need the move, as `BigObject(x)` is already an rvalue.